# Исчезновение открытых папок и вкладок в редакторе visual studio code при открытии файла через контекстное меню в проводнике

Tags: visual-studio-code, редактор-текста

У меня в VS code открыта вкладка с редактируемым файлом. Когда я в проводнике Windows в контекстном меню файла выбираю пункт "Открыть с помощью Code" в VS code появляется новая вкладка с этим самым файлом, при этом вкладка с уже открытым файлом остаётся на месте. Всё как и должно быть. Но если я предварительно закрою VS code и попытаюсь повторить действия, то вкладка с новым файлом откроется, но вкладка со старым пропадает.

Говоря другими словами если я открываю VS code не через exe файл, а при помощи выбора пункта "Открыть с помощью Code" в контекстном меню проводника Windows все открытые ранее файла и папки в VS code пропадают.

Пробовал найти решение в поиске, но находил решения только похожих более популярных проблем.

Почему это происходит и как можно это исправить?

Comment: Зачем открывать файлы по одиночке? В самом простом варианте - проект это несколько файлов в одном каталоге. И открывается весь каталог целиком.

Comment: Раньше такого не было и это очень удобно. У меня в VS code всегда была открыта папка с моим проектом, но иногда нужно просто посмотреть какой-то файл не относящийся к проекту и в таком случае папка с проектом пропадает и её придётся основать снова. Также бывает что нашёл какой-то нужный файл в проекте и хочется его открыть сразу из проводника, а не включать редактор и искать его там. Я это делаю и папка с проектом опять пропадает. Ну и в общем я привык заходить в редактор открывая сразу нужный файл, а не через exe.

Comment: _а не через exe(с)_ я и не говорил через exe, я имел ввиду открытие папки через контекстное меню.

Comment: Я конечно могу заходить в редактор открывая папку через контекстное меню и в таком случае у меня даже сохранятся открытые файлы, но если я уже нахожусь в папке с проектом проще открыть нужный файл сразу. И тут такая досада что это закрывает всё остальное. Может быть я немного непонятно объясняю зачем мне это нужно. Всё же я задал этот вопрос чтобы исправить это и хочу это сделать.

Comment: _Может быть я немного непонятно объясняю(c)_ Скорее сложно понять желаемое поведение. Вероятно была кастомная настройка. К примеру [window.restoreWindows: preserve](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_window-management) открывает последний проект и все ранее открытые "левые" файлы по контекст-меню любого файла.